# NotImplementedError for learn.TensorFlowEstimator.restore / TensorFlowRNNRegressor.restore

Tags: tensorflow

I had saved a model by using tensorflow.contrib.learn.TensorFlowRNNRegressor and I am currently trying to restore it. However, I got a NotImplementedError.

It seems that 10.0 or master does not implement "_restore".
It also does not have parameter "model_dir" to save/restore model like other regressors.
Is there a workaround? Thanks a lot.